# Orbeon 4.0.0.7m: form runner currency control rejects input with decimal separator ',' (comma) as invalid

Tags: orbeon

I have defined a form with currency controls and need to use a comma ',' as decimal separator. I have set the decimal separator (,) and grouping separator (.) in properties-local.xml accordingly (see details below).

When I enter a number without a comma, Orbeon accepts it and formats it as expected.

E.g., "15" becomes "€ 15,00".

However, the form does not accept input with a "," in it.

E.g., "15,00" leads to a validation error.

Inputting "15.00" is accepted, but incorrectly formatted by the currency control, namely

"15.00" becomes "€ 1.500,00"

Orbeon seems not to recognize the "," as decimal separator when input to the currency control.

Have I missed to set some additional property or the like? How can I write currency values with decimal commas? Any suggestions or ideas how to make this work?

Excerpt from properties-local.xml:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.currency.prefix" value="&#x20AC;"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.currency.digits-after-decimal" value="2"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.currency.decimal-separator" value=","/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.currency.grouping-separator" value="."/>

<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.number.prefix" value=""/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.number.digits-after-decimal" value="2"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.number.decimal-separator" value=","/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.xforms.xbl.fr.number.grouping-separator" value="."/>
```

Comment: Hi again! Please, can anyone give a hint regarding this problem? I wonder if I do something wrong or if this is excepted behaviour of Orbeon? Most problably, other European Orbeon users will have forms where numbers are input with a comma decimal separator. So, there should be a simple way to achieve this with Orbeon, but I have not found it yet... Any hint will be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, finally I modified `number.xbl`, and two small modifications in `number.xbl` do the job for me.

1. Find the modified `number.xbl` here - git://gist.github.com/3636583.git
2. Put this `number.xbl` into folder `resources/xbl/orbeon/number`